# Simple jQuery hover slide down, reverse to slide up?

Tags: jquery, menu, slideup, slidedown

I have the following simple slide down hover menu.

```
 $(function(){
$('.sub-menu').hide();
$('.menu-item').hover(
    function () {
        var target = $(this).children('ul');
        $.browser.msie ? target.show() : target.slideDown(150);
    },
    function () {
        var target = $(this).children('ul')
        $.browser.msie ? target.hide() : target.slideUp(150);
    }
);
```

});

It slides down .sub-menu as you hover over .menu-item and slides back up when you leave, perfect.

I need it to slide up .sub-menu when you hover over .menu-item, vise versa to the above really..

I've done the obvious of swapping the slideUp and slideDown but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Many thanks if you can :)

Comment: For curiosity, why aren't you animating for ie?

Comment: It works in IE, just without the slide.

Can this be done sliding up or a no no :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu-item').hover(
        function () {
            var target = $(this).children('ul');
            $.browser.msie ? target.hide() : target.slideUp(150);
        },
        function () {
            var target = $(this).children('ul')
            $.browser.msie ? target.show() : target.slideDown(150);
        }
    );
});
```

Should work, though I can't test it without more code.

Basically I'm assuming `.sub-menu` is already showing, so when you hover over .`menu-item` you want to hide it, correct?

All that I changed was: I swapped around the two functions and removed the `$('.sub-menu').hide();` that was at the beginning. It doesn't need hiding before it actually slides up.

**Edit:** Working on your latest example.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/GwBuj/3/

What I did is:

- Change `#button` and `#slider` to
  classes (`.button` and `.slider`)
- Modify the CSS accordingly, and
  changed `.slider` CSS to allow for
  multiple buttons (You had it
  positioned absolutely which wouldn't
  allow you to see the others)
- Adjust the JQuery code to work on multiple
  buttons
- Added another button to show
  you that it works

Comment: Thanks for that i see what you've done, basically i need a reverse of it sliding down, so it needs to be hidden before it slides up above the menu.

So its hidden then slides up, currently its hidden and slides down on hover...

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/Bw9wJ, currently sliding down on hover, need it to slide up above the parent hover...?

Comment: *Update*

Think i have managed it http://jsfiddle.net/GwBuj/ is running :)

However, now i need to figure out how to apply it to multiple buttons across a navigation like the one above... that possible?

Comment: Brilliant Archonix, thank you so much.

I assume it can work with all sorts of html, li lists etc as well, now the basis is there?

Thank you. :)

Comment: @Jezthomp - Yup, all it needs is the 'button' `(.button)` and another element that contains the links. It can be a `ul` and the links could be all `li` - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/GwBuj/4/

Comment: @Archonix, i've come across a bit of a problem, i need to add a class to the parent button and then remove it when you leave the drop down/hover. Tried this http://snipt.org/molnj/ but it doesn't remove the class when you leave... :(

Comment: Brilliant thank you @Archonix tried something similar to that but it just added an active class to all the buttons.